# Making a nested JSON from '/' delimited CSV headers

Tags: python, jquery, node.js, json, bash

My CSV headers look something like

| from/email | from/name | to/0/email | personalization/0/email/ | personalization/0/data/first_name | personalization/0/data/company_name | personalization/0/data/job_title | template_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| me@x.com | Me | mike@x.com | mike@x.com | Mike | X Inc. | Chef, Meat Grill | 12345 |
| me@x.com | Me | lauren@y.com | lauren@y.com | Lauren | Y Inc. | Bartender | 12345 |

Output should be:

```
[
 {
   "from": {
      "email": "me@x.com",
      "name": "Me"
   },
   "to": [
      {
         "email": "mike@x.com"
      }
   ],
   "personalization": [
      {
         "email": "mike@x.com",
         "data": {
            "first_name": "Mike",
            "company_name": "X Inc.",
            "job_title": "Chef, Meat Grill"
         }
      }
   ],
   "template_id": "123456"
},
```

I tried

```
csvjson input.csv output.csv
```

```
csvtojson input.csv output.csv
```

```
csv2json input.csv output.csv
```

```
python3 app.py

import csv 
import json 

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
      
    #read csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 

        #convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader: 
            #add this python dict to json array
            jsonArray.append(row)
  
    #convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)
          
csvFilePath = r'outputt1.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'outputt1.json'
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

```
node app.js

const CSVToJSON = require('csvtojson');

// convert users.csv file to JSON array
CSVToJSON().fromFile('outputt1.csv')
    .then(from => {

        // from is a JSON array
        // log the JSON array
        console.log(from);
    }).catch(err => {
        // log error if any
        console.log(err);
    });
```

All output some variation of single-line JSON with no nesting. Please help.

Comment: Do you have a sample of what your csv file looks like?

Comment: And your usage of the `bash` and `python` tags is backed by what kind of context?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The relationship between the Data you show and the desired Output does match logically. Comma Separated Values (CSV) would imply the use of `,` and not `/`. Can you provide an example of your content or data?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out @HaiVu I have added an example of the data as well as an example that reflects that some people have combined job titles separated by a comma.

Comment: You have both Python and Javascript.  In what language do you want this to be done?

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm more familiar with python but of course any solution is acceptable

Comment: Did @TimRoberts Python solution work for you? If so, please accept their answer.

Answer (score 0):

This does it.  It's bit ugly, but there are some strange special cases parsing those headers.

```
import csv
import json

def process( headers, row ):
    gather = {}
    for h,r in zip(headers,row):
        cur = gather
        key = 'BASE'
        for p in h.split('/'):
            print(gather,cur, key,p)
            if p.isdigit():
                p = int(p)
                if key not in cur:
                    cur[key] = []
                if len(cur[key]) < p+1:
                    cur[key].append({})
            else:
                if isinstance(cur,dict) and key not in cur:
                    cur[key] = {}
            cur = cur[key]
            key = p
        cur[key] = r.strip()
    return gather['BASE']

fcsv = csv.reader(open('x.csv'))
headers = next(fcsv)

data = []
for row in fcsv:
    data.append( process( headers, row ) )
print(json.dumps(data,indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "from": {
            "email": "me@x.com",
            "name": "Me"
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "mike@x.com"
            }
        ],
        "personalization": [
            {
                "email": "mike@x.com",
                "data": {
                    "first_name": "Mike",
                    "company_name": "X Inc.",
                    "job_title": "Chef"
                }
            }
        ],
        "template_id": "Meat Grill"
    },
    {
        "from": {
            "email": "me@x.com",
            "name": "Me"
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "lauren@y.com"
            }
        ],
        "personalization": [
            {
                "email": "lauren@y.com",
                "data": {
                    "first_name": "Lauren",
                    "company_name": "Y Inc.",
                    "job_title": "Bartender"
                }
            }
        ],
        "template_id": "12345"
    }
]
```